# How to get data between date range in django rest_framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to fetch some data between two dates, but got an error that is "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'". How I solve this issue?

**views.py**

```
class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        user_obj = Payload.objects.all()
        usr = self.request.user
        print(usr)
        user_data = TestSerializer(user_obj, many=True)
        return Response({'status':'success'})    

    def post(self, request):
        serializers = TestSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializers.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            start_date = serializers.validated_data['start_date']
            end_date = serializers.validated_data['end_date']
            user_id = serializers.validated_data['user_id']
            user_obj = Payload.objects.filter(user=user_id, timestamp__gte=start_date,timestamp__lte=end_date)
            sr = TestModelSerializer(user_obj, many=True)
            return Response({'status':sr.data}, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            print(serializers.errors,"errors")
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    start_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    end_date = serializers.DateTimeField()

class TestModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = Payload
    fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class Payload(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    input_values = models.CharField(max_length=20) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.input_values
```

**trackback**
[image]

Comment: Can you please post a traceback? It's unclear where the error is coming from. Also, you don't need `if serializers.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`, since raise_exception flag will, well, raise an exception if the data is invalid, instead of returning boolean

Comment: Btw, usually, you would name the variable `serializer`, not `serializers`, since it's a single instance, also you are shadowing the 'serializers' package from the imports

Comment: Alexandr, serializers is a variable. It's not a major deal.

Comment: I attached the traceback image above.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `timestamp__gte` should be `datetime` object. Like in [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#date) example.

Im not sure that `serializer` datetime fields returns string or datetime object, but error tell that is `string`.

Comment: One can query with strings, actually, if in the right format. But the serializer will convert them to the datetime objects anyway

Comment: In a model.py timestamp is a column, not date

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_filter = dict(created__gte=datetime.now() - timedelta(30), created__lte=datetime.now()) 

you can filter more customize 
start_date = '2021-05-21'
end_date = '2021-05-24'
date_filter = dict(created__gte=start_date), created__lte=end_date)

objs  = Klash.objects.filter(**date_filter) # Klash = your model name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this.

```
Payload.objects.filter(user=user_id, timestamp__range=[start_date,end_date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that was not obvious at all, but I've figured it out. So the error says `'str' object has no attribute 'values'`. According to the traceback, the line in question is `for field in self.fields.values()`, where `self` is the instance of `TestModelSerializer`.

Taking a closer look, there is a mistake in the serializer definition, which sets `fields = '__all__'`, and `'__all__'` is the string which raises an error. The proper definition should be

```
class TestModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Payload
        fields = '__all__'
```